# Splitting a string into specific result in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an exact string below

```
string a = "@David<br/>0044332 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26"
```

I am trying to split the above string into the result below

```
string productNo = "0044332"
string customercomment = "0044332 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26"
```

How can i split it to remove the @David, get the productNo and then the rest as the comment from string a?

Comment: `string.split(productNo )[1]`

Comment: I mean, if you know the string starts with "<stuff><br/>" then really you just need to find the index of the first <br/> and slice after it

Comment: I assume you want Alice's message too?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `replace()` to match on the pieces you want and pull them out.

```js
var test = "@David<br/>0044332 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26";
var orderNumber;
var comment;

test.replace(/^[^>]+<br\/>(\d+)(.+)$/, function(_, match1, match2){
  orderNumber = match1;
  comment = match1 + match2;
});

console.log(orderNumber);
console.log(comment);
```

Comment: Missing the second one

Comment: What is missing?  It looks like it matches his second snippet? @mplungjan

Comment: I might be wrong, but I assume OP also wants the second product ID

Comment: Given the makup of the string, my assumption would be he might want to stick it on the page and let the html render for David to see his messages.  In which case keeping the <br> can make sense.  @mplungjan

Comment: In my opinion, this approach is fine, I think the `product number` is always the same for all the commentaries (`John` and `Alice`). I will just add a reference so the OP can learn about the `replacement` function of `replace()`.

Comment: Your approach is fine, just that the numbers of comments is dynamic. Might not be just match1 and match2

Comment: @Devora if the string format always starts with @stuff<br/> then match1 will always be the order number and match2 will always be all the text after then first product number.  Regardless of comment count.

Answer (score 1):

If you first split your `string` by `<br>` then you can get an array with the different data:

```js
const a = "@David<br/>0044332 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26";

let data = a.split(/<br\/>/);
console.log(data);
```

Now, for get the `productNo` you can perform a [String::match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the first match of sequential numbers on any of the elements of the previous array that isn't at `index 0`. You have all the messages on the array `indexes 1 to array.length`, but if you need to get they together again, you can [Array::join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) they back.

```js
const a = "@David<br/>0044332 Awesome product 123! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26";

let data = a.split(/<br\/>/);
console.log(data);

// Get product number from string on index 1.
let productNo = data[1].match(/\w+/)[0];

// Join back all messages.
let customerComments = data.slice(1).join("<br>");

// Show information.
console.log(productNo);
console.log(customerComments);
```

Comment: This works well, i am just not sure if <br\> is saved to mongo, and when i retrieve it, will it have <br\> as part of the string?

Comment: @Devora I have not worked with `MongoDB`. So i'm not sure about that, but I believe there will be no problem.

Comment: any idea how to split if the message is like this? 
theres hidden shift+enter
`string a = "@David
0044332 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02
0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26"`

Comment: @Devora have you tried `a.split(/\n/);` or `a.split(/\r/);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also want Alice's bits?

```js
const a = "@David<br/>0044331 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26"
const parts = a.split("<br/>")
parts.shift()
console.log(parts)
parts.forEach(function(part) {
  let bits = part.split(" ");
  console.log(bits[0],":",bits.slice(1).join(" "))
});
```

Comment: Yes i do wan Alice aswell, but just keep the rest of it string as it is, only remove the @David and the first <br\>   string customercomment = "0044332 Awesome product! (John) 2013-09-02<br/>0044332 Delivered on time (Alice) 2014-02-26"